# Proper way to encode a (relative) URL using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, apache, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm trying to encode the following relative URL using PHP:

```
/tracks/add/5449326
```

I've tried using rawurlencode and urlencode.

Which made it look something like: `%2Ftracks%2Fadd%2F5449326`

I'm going to use this URL in an AJAX call.

The URL I am trying to make the call to is:

```
/overlay/add-track/{param1}/{param2}
```

{param1} is just some id

{param2} is the encoded url

However when I try to make the call I get a 404.

From the looks of it, it is trying to make a call to:

```
/overlay/add-track/1//tracks/add/5449326
```

So it looks like it's trying to access the decoded string.

Any ideas how to fix this?

PHP

```
$url = rawurlencode('/tracks/add/5449326');    
echo '<a href="/overlay/add-track/1/'.$url.'">Add</a>';
```

JS (jQuery)
    var href = $('a').attr('href');

```
$.ajax({
  url: href,
  type: 'POST',
  data: {},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data)
  {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

EDIT

```
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(eps|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|jpeg|doc|xls|doc|pdf|txt|ppt|zip)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

  RewriteCond "/path/public/%{REQUEST_URI}" !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can't you just use GET variable for {param2}? Like `/overlay/add-track/{param1}?param2={param2}`

Comment: What happens if you type `/overlay/add-track/1/%2Ftracks%2Fadd%2F5449326` into your address bar? Of course with the domain stuff prepended.

Comment: Should work, does your access log explicitly state the wrong url?

Comment: what about base64 encoding and decoding of the url parameter?

Comment: @Znarkus: I get a 404. However if I change to encode slashes to another character e.g. and `x` it works.

Comment: @Muhammad Yasir: I would really like to prevent me from doing that.

Comment: @PeeHaa Any particular reasons?

Comment: @PeeHaa I think your URL rewriting is broken. Could you please post your .htaccess?

Comment: @Znarkus: added. @Muhammad:Even if I would go the ?param way I still would like to know why it doesn't work. That's how I roll :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoded slash is probably not allowed by the webserver resulting in a default 404.

For apache see:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Either the apache config needs to be changed or you need to work around it by replacing the slash/backslash with something else.

edit:
You could try a double urlencode and then decodeURI() in javascript.